# pymongo--How to get the true inventory cost of a product from mongodb

Tags: aggregate, pymongo

Below is a collection of data (collection of mongodb)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiiiL.png)

```
name    buyAsale    num   price
a       buy         10    8
a       buy         20    7
a       sale        -20   11
a       sale        -10   13
a       buy         20    6
a       buy         30    8
b       buy         11    6
b       buy         15    4
b       sale        -16   5.5
b       sale        -6    6
b       sale        -4    5.5
b       buy         12    6
b       buy         15    8
```

I expect to get the real inventory cost of products A and B：

The result I want is：

```
name   cost
a      7.2
b      7.11
```

### The inventory price of the product I want to obtain should be the average cost of A's remaining inventory (residual inventory cost after first-in first-out) (the same is true for b)

If I use aggregation, I get the wrong result like below:

```
name   cost
a      4.6
b      6.37
```

The code I got for this error result is as follows:

```
import pymongo
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["licai"]
mycol = mydb["aaa"]

group = {'$group': {
    '_id': {'name': '$name'},
    'num': {'$sum': '$num'},
    'Amount': {'$sum': {'$multiply':['$num','$price']}},
}}
project = {'$project': {
    '_id': 0,
    'name': '$_id.name',
    'cost':{'$divide': ['$Amount', '$num']},
}}
mydoc=mycol.aggregate([group, project])
data = pd.DataFrame(mydoc)
print(data)
```

Comment: Or can only take out all the data to achieve through the loop？

Comment: If I run the numbers manually for `a` I get 230 for the sumproduct and 50 for the sum so the weighted average is 4.6 as calculated.